# How to use Ajax(?) in Django to update an image from the server

Tags: python, ajax, django

Here is my simple Template:

```
{% extends "base.template" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Status{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if status1 %}
      {% with "images/"|add:status1|add:".gif" as static_image %}
        <img src= "{% static static_image%}" width='100' height='100'/>
      {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if status2 %}
      {% with "images/"|add:status2|add:".gif" as static_image %}
        <img src= "{% static static_image%}" width='100' height='100'/>
      {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if status3 %}
      {% with "images/"|add:status3|add:".gif" as static_image %}
        <img src= "{% static static_image%}" width='100' height='100'/>
      {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if status4 %}
      {% with "images/"|add:status4|add:".gif" as static_image %}
        <img src= "{% static static_image%}" width='100' height='100'/>
      {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my view:

```
def getStatus(request):
  status = get_template("template");
  stats = getStats()
  if len(stats) == 1:
    rtn = status.render(Context({'status':stats[0]}))
  elif len(stats) == 2:
    rtn = status.render(Context({'status1':stats[0],
                        'status2':stats[1]}))
  elif len(stats) == 3:
    rtn = status.render(Context({'status1':stats[0],
                        'status2':stats[1],
                        'status3':stats[2]}))
  elif len(stats) == 4:
    rtn = status.render(Context({'status1':stats[0],
                        'status2':stats[1],
                        'status3':stats[2],
                        'status4':stats[3]}))
  return HttpResponse(rtn)
```

This is all working.  Periodically, the results of getStats() (on the server-side) changes and I want to change the image that is presented in the view on the user's screen.  I would prefer not to use html refresh and update the entire page.  I want to only update the image (and only when it actually changes.)

I assume the answer is Ajax... I have looked for simple examples of Ajax and Django and not found anything that makes sense (to me.)  Any suggestions would be most welcomed.

**EDIT:**
Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from garageMonitor.views import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url('time', currentTime),
)
```

Here is my base.template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Garage Status</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}
    <hr>
    <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my time.template:

```
{% extends "base.template" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}Current Time{% endblock %}
  {% block content %}
    Here is time.template
    {{ time }}
    <onload="refresh()" src="/static/garageMonitor/scripts/refreshTime.js">
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my views.py:

```
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
import os
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

def currentTime(request):
  status = get_template("time.template");
  now = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
  rtn = status.render(Context({'time':now}))
  return HttpResponse(rtn)
```

Here is my refreshTime.js:

```
function refresh() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '{% url garageMonitor/monitor-test %}',
    success: function(data) {
      blah
      $('#test').html(data);
    }
    setInterval("refresh()", 1000);
  });
};

$(function(){
  refresh();
});
```

From what I understand (and that is not that much!), the refresh() function in the file /static/garageMonitor/scripts/refreshTime.js should be called when the time page loads. The function should then call itself every second.

The page is loading correctly, but it is not refreshing.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial, https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Answer (score 1):

1. setup the server side end point to accept the post request
2. read this [ajax api from jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

ex:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "url/path/some",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

**url**: is the end point in server side.

**data**: json data that goes on body request.

**method**: POST http protocol.

simply as that.

> You can call this ajax after the user click on button to send the image

Answer (score 1):

Using `Ajax` means you make `asynchronous javascript` calls to the server. This can be done via a `javascript` script in-page or a linked file. The script would call the `GET` method on your server url, which would return the changed data.

What you (probably) need is, every few time intervals,

1. send a `GET` request  to the server to check if there are any updates
2. if the server responds with an affirmation, send another `GET` request to receive those updates
3. update the elements with the updated information

There are two things you would need to develop here -

**ONE**: javascript code to send `ajax` requests and update elements (using `jQuery` since it's of much help to make things easier)

```js
/** attach to document load or ready state */
function update_stuff() {
    $.get('/server_url_check_updates/', function(data ,status) {
        if (data.has_updates === 'YES') {
            /** send request to get updated data */
            $.get('/server_url_get_updates/', function(data, status) {
                /** update your elements */
            }
        }
    }
}
setTimeout(update_stuff, interval_in_seconds);
```

**TWO**. server code that handles `GET` requests

```python
import json
import HttpRequest

# map to /server_url_check_updates/
def check_for_updates(request):
    # see if it's a GET request
    if request.GET:
        has_updates = True # True/False depending on updates
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({'has_updates': True, }),
            content_type="application/json")

# map to /server_url_get_updates/
def send_updates(request):
    if request.GET:
        # create dictionary of your objects
        dictionary_of_your_objects = {}
        data = json.dumps(dictionary_of_you_objects)
        # return them lumped together or as separate objects
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({'updates': data, }),
            content_type="application/json")
```

You can add additional code to check whether the `GET` requests are valid, use only one url for both functions (check the `GET` parameter to see what is being requested), etc. See the following links for more information on this:

**js/jquery/ajax**

[javascript - ajax calls (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp)

[jquery - ajax calls (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

[jquery - GET (query)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

**django**

[django - request/response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/)

Comment: thanks for your input kicker86.  I think this is what I want, but am not sure where to put the update_stuff function.  I believe you mean it should be in the template?  If so, I am lost to how to add this.  Also, I believe that urls.py will need entries for both send_updates and check_for_updates?

Comment: It feels like you're quite new to `javascript`, in which case, you can get a quick tutorial on how to embed and use js in html pages. For now, the answer is: you declare a `<script>` tag in your `<body>` that contain the javascript code. The function needs to be called whenever you want to start the auto-refresh. If you want it to start as soon as the page loads, put in the `document on load` function. If you want it to start whenever a button is pressed, put it in the `onClick` handler of that button. You can search for these terms to learn about them and get examples.

Comment: You are right, javascript is not my forte (and for now, I don't need it to be ;-)  Where in my Django template should I put it?  I am not using a button here, so I don't need that part (just the periodic refresh of an image.)

Comment: I hate to ask to be spoon-fed, but I really just have the one page with the one image that needs to be updated if the image has changed.  I am trying to get this project going and there are soooo many aspects to it, the web page is only a tiny piece and I have a lot more pieces to pull together.  If necessary, I'll just put a refresh tag in the html and update the entire page every second, but it looks tacky.  If someone could please be specific about how to go about this using Django, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you need much more code-specific help than just helpful pointers, you can send me your github repo link, and I'll submit a PR with my suggested changes. For the answer: you can look at how to execute a function on document load using javascript or jQuery, then execute the ajax calls every xx seconds on document load.

Comment: Thank kicker86.I am not using github.com (have my own SVN server at home.) for now, I'll look into your suggestion. If I get lost in the weeds, I create a repo link and get back with you. 
Again, thank you for your suggestions